# For in c with no params

Tags: c, for-loop

Sometimes when im reading code it appears to be written for with no params to load

Like this:

```
for(;;)
{
/*Some piece of code*/
}
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: It's an infinite loop.

Comment: Any of the three parts of the `for` syntax can be omitted.

Comment: … and if it is the middle part, i.e., the condition, that is omitted, it will never end, unless you `break` (or `return`) from the loop body. (edit: or `goto` outside the loop, or `exit` or `longjmp`, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any combination of the three expressions can omitted, including all of them.

If the first or third expression is omitted, no code is evaluated when those expression would be evaluated. (If both of these are omitted, one effectively has a pure `while` loop.)

If the middle expression is omitted, it's as if a true expression was provided. This creates a loop that can only be exited using `break`, `return`, `exit` and long jumps.

For example, the following loops until a valid answer is given.

```c
int x;
for (;;) {              // Or `while (1)`
   display_prompt();
   x = get_answer();
   if (is_valid(x))
      break;

   printf("Invalid input\n");
}
```

Comment: Trivia: Perl accepts `while ()` in addition to `for (;;)` as equivalents to `while (1)`

Answer (score 1):

The `for` loop has three parts: initialization, test, and update.

Any of these can be omitted. By having *none* of them included, you've created an infinite loop and need to include some kind of test with `break` inside the body of the loop.

For the same effect, one can use a `while` loop:

```
while (1) {

}
```

Comment: Omitting only the middle of the three sections of a for loop ( `for(int i = 0;;i++)` ) is sufficient to make it infinite.

Comment: Or by omitting the update, assuming nothing is updated in the body and the rest doesn't have a side effect which performs the update.